# Ubuntu 11.10 java.awt.Desktop not supported

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, desktop

I am receiving a java.awt.Desktop not supported error.

```
if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
URI uri = new URI(twitterUser.link)
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported on the current platform
    at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Unknown Source)

I am running this on Ubuntu 11.10 using Gnome 3.2 and java 1.7.0_03

I have read online this error occurs because gnome is missing specific libraries, but I am not sure what libraries gnome is missing.

Many thanks in advance for your advice and help.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that you're using Java 7?  Which type of Java is it (OpenJDK, Oracle)?

Comment: Its Oracle. I am just using the latest version of Java. I know that I need to be using at least Java 6 in order to utilize java.awt.Desktop class